# Linux exit function

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand linux syscalls mechanism. I am reading a book and it in the book it says that exit function look like that(with gdb):

```
mov $0x0,%ebx
mov $0x1,%eax
80 int $0x80
```

I understand that this is a syscall to exit, but in my Debian it looks like that:

```
jmp    *0x8049698
push   $0x8
jmp    0x80482c0
```

maybe can someone explain me why it's not the same? When I try to do disas on 0x80482c0
gdb prints me:

> No function contains specified address.

Also, can someone give me a good reference to Linux Internals material(as Windows internals)?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you get `jmp    *0x8049698....` on your Debian? Did you disassemblied a program?

Answer (score 2):

The function you most likely called is `exit()` from C Standard Library (see [man 3 exit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit)). This function is a library function which, in turn, calls `SYS_exit` system call, but not being a system call itself. You will not see that good looking `int 0x80` code in your C program disassembly. All existing functions (`exit()`, `syscall()`, etc.) are called from some library, so your program is only doing call to that library, and those functions are not belong to your program.

If you want to see exactly that `int 0x80` code -- you can inline that asm code in your C application. But this is considered a bad practice, though, as your code become architecture-dependent (only applicable to x86 architecture, in your case).

> can someone give me a good reference to Linux Internals material

The code itself is the best up-to-date reference. All books are more or less outdated. Also look into `Documentation/` directory in kernel sources.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So where can I actually see that int 0x80? I mean, where is the "OS" implementation of the exit function so I will be able to see actually the syscall? It should be in a system so file no? It's nice that I can see the sources, but I mean more high level mechanism. Because I am a comming from the Windows world, and I am used to the Windows mechanism.

Comment: Also, in that book, the author compile a simple c program that calls exit(0) and then he can see the exit function implementation (int 0x80):
'gdb exit
This GDB was configured as “i386-redhat-linux-gnu”...
(gdb) disas _exit
Dump of assembler code for function _exit:
0x0804d9bc <_exit+0>: mov 0x4(%esp,1),%ebx
0x0804d9c0 <_exit+4>: mov $0xfc,%eax
0x0804d9c5 <_exit+9>: int $0x80
0x0804d9c7 <_exit+11>: mov $0x1,%eax
0x0804d9cc <_exit+16>: int $0x80
0x0804d9ce <_exit+18>: hlt
0x0804d9cf <_exit+19>: nop
End of assembler dump.'

Comment: @gtalst12 Actual syscall implementation is somewhere in glibc. You can look in sources. Or you can compile your C program with `-static` flag so that your program binary has glibc embedded. In that case you should be able to see that `int 0x80` code.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I just did it with -static, and now I am able to see the int 80! Thanks!